# How to find first, second and third highest value in a given vector without sorting in C++?

Tags: c++

Here's what I did for the code

```
int maxIndex = 0; int secPlace = 0; int minIndex = 0; 
for(int k = 0; k < w.size(); k++){  //Finding First Place
    if(w.at(k) > w.at(maxIndex)) {                                       
       maxIndex = k;                                                   
      }
}
 for(int a = 0; a < w.size(); a++){ //Finding Second Place
    if( a!= maxIndex && w.at(secPlace) < w.at(a)){
       secPlace = a; 
    }
 }

for(int b = 0; b < w.size(); b++){   //Finding third place
    if(b != maxIndex && b != secPlace && w.at(minIndex) < w.at(b)){

       minIndex = b;
 }
```

I know that this code won't work if I have the user enter values such as 10, 8, 6 because the the loop for finding the second place and third place will never come true. I have no idea where to go from here to solve this problem.

Comment: Q: How to find first, second and third highest value in a given vector without sorting? A: One obvious alternative is to iterate: Set high1, high2 and high3 = 1st element, then compare with the subsequent elements in a loop.

Comment: Does [`std::partial_sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort) work as it doesn't sort the whole array?

Comment: I don't think Im allowed to use any kind of sorting @KenY-N

Comment: ah I thought of that and I tried doing it but I have no idea on how I would write the code for that @paulsm4

Comment: It's going to be not much different from finding the higest.

Comment: @paulsm4, That's not going to work if the first element is the highest.

Comment: So what are the restrictions?  Can you use a temporary array to hold the 3 largest values?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ya i think i could use a temp array to hold the largest three value...

Comment: ok, do you know what a min-heap is?  Are you allowed to use the algorithm functions?  The solution can be generalized to hold the largest n element, not just 3 if you used those techniques.  I could post as an answer, but don't want to waste posting it if it isn't something you would consider.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie sorry man I have no idea what you are talking about but when you said using a temp array to hold the largest three value it gave me an idea of like using the same code I had and using like one of the functions vectors have of like storing the largest value in a diff array and deleting that index from the vector, idk if that will work doe

Comment: @MATHASKER A heap is just a special way to store the numbers so that the smallest (or largest) value is always the first value and the subsequent numbers in the array also share the property, where the number is larger (or smaller) than its children.  If you were to extend the question to store the last `n` elements without sorting, you will learn pretty quickly what a heap is as this is the classical way to solve this.  No time than the present to [learn what a heap is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap).  Note that an array can be used to create a heap, but a vector is more suitable.

Comment: @MATHASKER [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d09768cee9fdc067).  Just in case you're curious.  I know it's advanced in terms of how to solve a question like this in general, but at least you get a heads up on one way (and again, the classical way) of solving the question.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ahh ok I'll look into that thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could store the highest values in a `vector`, insert higher values into that `vector` and limit it to size 3 :

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> w, m;
    for (auto a : w)
    {
        bool added = false;
        for (auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); it++)
        {
            if (a > *it)
            {
                added = true;
                m.insert(it, a);
                if (m.size() > 3)
                {
                    m.resize(3);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!added && m.size() < 3)
        {
            m.push_back(a);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ah thank you for responding, my class hasn't covered some stuff you did up there so I'm having a little bit of hard time figuring out what that means.